# How to set dynamically Javascript variables to PHP in CakePHP?

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

I need to set a PHP variable dynamically with Javascript. I googled but all I got was PHP to Javascript-conversion.

Is there a way to pass Javascript variable to PHP? And is there a helper in CakePHP to do the job? And can it be done dynamically (without refreshing page)?

Comment: Have a look at ajax technology.

Comment: If you are talking about web browsers client-server (not embedded javascript) you can't pass javascript variable to a PHP, all you can is to use AJAX technology to do a "hidden" request to a server.

Comment: So I am able to have for example an onclick-function with javascript that changes for example a PHP session-variable without refreshing page? ajax technology is the key? @user1759572

Comment: Yes. AJAX lets you to do kind of seamless request to a server (where you can set session variables, update db value, etc.). Check http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ If you are using jquery, see http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: Your question is a bit vague on what variable you want to pass to PHP. If it's something you are showing on a form, you can use Javascript to change the value of the form input. Otherwise use AJAX to call a Controller's action and test for AJAX.

Comment: @GustavoCarreno actually I need to save to database without refreshing page, because otherwise my iframe (which is on some url) will lose its location on refresh.

Comment: @hemppa Then you really have to deal with AJAX calls to your Controller's actions. Have a look at: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html and http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html